# Not getting location in Android 8.0.0 Oreo

Tags: location, react-native, android-8.0-oreo, android-fusedlocation

I am building an app in React-Native and need to have location access as per the requirement.

I have tried using `react-native-fused-location` for the same, as below.

```
           FusedLocation.setLocationInterval(20000);
           FusedLocation.setFastestLocationInterval(15000);
          FusedLocation.setSmallestDisplacement(10);

          FusedLocation.setLocationPriority(
            FusedLocation.Constants.HIGH_ACCURACY
          );
          FusedLocation.startLocationUpdates();


          FusedLocation.getFusedLocation().then(location => {

            if (location != null) {
              let initialPosition = JSON.stringify(location);
              this.state.latitude = location.latitude;
              this.state.longitude = location.longitude;
              this.state.timestamp = location.timestamp;
              this.state.initialPosition = initialPosition;


            } else {
              alert("Location unavailable, please try later");
            }
          }).catch(error => {  // fused location catch
             console.log("location retrieval failed");
          });
```

The only output, I am receiving with the above code, in case of *Oreo 8.0.0* is **E/request: 100**.

also tried the other way as below

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
            location => {
              console.log("inside watchPosition location");
              if (location != null) {
                console.log("location is not null");
                let initialPosition = JSON.stringify(location.coords);
                this.state.latitude = location.coords.latitude;
                this.state.longitude = location.coords.longitude;
                this.state.timestamp = location.coords.timestamp;
                this.state.initialPosition = initialPosition;


              } else {
                alert("Location unavailable, please try later");
              }
            },
            error => {
              console.log("calling ShowHideActivityIndicator,  getLocationWithNavigate (ios)");

              this.ShowHideActivityIndicator(false);
              alert("location retrieval failed");
              console.log(error);
            },
            { timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true, distanceFilter: 10 }
          );
```

But getting same output in both of the above codes, that is unable to get the location specifically in Android **Oreo 8.0.0**. Even the location retrieving callback is not even called. Though in other versions, including **Oreo 8.1.0**, and lower version devices, including Marshmallow and Nougat, it seems working fine.

Though, if I turn on the fake GPS in *Oreo 8.0.0*, then it seems to be able to get the location. I am unable to figure out, what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

mention to google document:

In an effort to reduce power consumption, Android 8.0 (API level 26) limits how frequently background apps can retrieve the user's current location. Apps can receive location updates only a few times each hour.[Background Location Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html)